# Trigger webpack build WITHOUT command line in Node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Is there some way to trigger a webpack build *without* using the command line `webpack build` task in a node.js script? I know I can use the `exec` function to execute a command line task, but I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve the command line at all.

I'm looking for something that works like

```js
import webpack from "webpack";
await webpack.build(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the webpack Node API (https://webpack.js.org/api/node/).

Create a `webpack` instance, as specified in the docs, like so:

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';

const compiler = webpack({}, (err, stats) => {
  if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
    // ...
  }
  // Done processing
});
```

Then, use the `run` method on `compiler` to, as the docs say, "kickstart all compilation work".

```js
compiler.run(() => console.log('Done'));
```